# Locating possible marriage between English woman and Danish man in (probably) late 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, england, vital-records, denmark

I am deadlocked in the identification of my great-grandfather.

A DNA test has identified an individual (in Denmark) who is suggested to be a near-relation of mine, but he has not responded to attempts to contact him.

However, I wonder if the relationship is to a sibling of Cecil Zohrab Ede (CZ Ede). CZ Ede's younger brother emigrated to the US and Australia. There was an older sister who disappears, and also a younger sister (see [this FamilySearch census record for 1871](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VB6B-BD9)).

How can I determine whether one of these sisters married the ancestors of my DNA match in Denmark?

Comment: The English in your question needs improvement.  If you can find someone more fluent in English to help you write your questions, it will make them easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 4):

We had established in previous answers that a fragment of the family tree can be at http://zohrabfamily.atwebpages.com/ztbltre3.html (lines 252-256) and you have reminded us of the 1871 Census record.

There appear to have been 4 daughters with the following information from the General Register Office index of birth, marriages and death:

- Mat(h)ilde Helen Ede born Jan/Mar 1861 Altrincham 8a 153 died Oct/Dec 1928 Monmouth 11a 32 aged 67. No record of marriage.
- Lore Gwendoline Ede born Apr/Jun 1865 Altrincham 8a 158 died Oct/Dec 1919 Chorlton 8c 713 aged 54 (http://zohrabfamily.atwebpages.com/ztbltre3.html says she died unmarried)
- Mabel Beatrice Ede born Jan/Mar 1875 Altrincham 8a 188 died Oct/Dec 1946 Ross 9a 81 aged 71. No record of marriage.
- Freda Carlene Ede born Oct/Dec 1871 Altrincham 8a 171 died Jan/Mar 1933 Monmouth 11a 39 aged 61
  married Cecil Burleigh Crampton in Jan/Mar 1901 Chorlton 8c 1043 ((http://zohrabfamily.atwebpages.com/ztbltre3.html says she died "sp", sin prole, without children)

You haven't explained how the Danish DNA connection connects you to the Edes. Although it's possible that Mathilde Helen Ede or Mabel Beatrice Ede married outside the UK, the fact that they both died with their maiden names would suggest they did not marry anywhere.

I'm afraid that the suggestion you are making is unlikely. Without understanding how the DNA has been connected to Denmark, it is hard to take this forward.

Comment: I think relation isn't between Danish man and me.In Japan ,as DNA test business is in USA and other country,many scholars say it isn' t theoretically.I think so too.Because other candidates in Japan, he and i have nothing in common.I will investigate by other method. I think C.Z.Ede is great-grandfather.In circumstantial evidence suggests C.Z Ede is husband of  my great-grandmother.When he died in shanghai,he was bachelor on records(National Archives).Mr. and Mrs.Ede got on the ship in Japan.This records exist.But I don't know Mrs.Ede is who.But C.Z.Ede wasn't bachelor in Japan.

Comment: @Akira Have you been able to find any information about the ship's arrival from Japan? If the record in Japan says "Mr & Mrs Ede" it is possible that a record on arrival (by which I mean immigration records) might say more. Was the ship going to Shanghai? Also, have you tried to obtain his probate record which I mentioned in a previous reply (see http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C1948323)? This should give details of who he left his money to.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This answer is long. So I will write another  question.

Comment: In Japan family registration is exist. But a man or woman marriage with foreigner,there's no record of foreigner. Today the foreigner's name is recorded only about their children's father.  But formerly this records isn't exist.In England, if a woman marriage with foreigner,is his name recorded? I heard no family registration is in English bloc.